# terminology on orthogonal matix

Tags: linear-algebra

I found the term 'orthogonal matrix' pretty confusing. According to wikipedia, its columns are orthonornal, but then what are matrices whose columns are orthogonal but not nornalized supposed to be called?

Comment: Is there an actual need for naming such a thing?

Comment: Those matrices, instead of representing a pure rotation/reflection, represent a rotation and a scaling - as all matrices do, by the QR decomposition

Answer (score 0):

I found the following comments from wikipedia which I think is good enough for my question:

A real square matrix is orthogonal if and only if its columns form an orthonormal basis of the Euclidean space ℝn with the ordinary Euclidean dot product, which is the case if and only if its rows form an orthonormal basis of ℝn. It might be tempting to suppose a matrix with orthogonal (not orthonormal) columns would be called an orthogonal matrix, but such matrices have no special interest and no special name; they only satisfy MTM = D, with D a diagonal matrix.